# Please explain the rationale behind this simple javascript interview question

Tags: javascript

Consider this program:

```
(function(x){
  delete x;
  return x;
})(1);
```

What is the output?

It happens to be `1` and not `undefined` as I expected. I thought `x` purely is in the scope of function and deleting it inside the function should have made it inaccessible to outside it.

Can someone throw a little light on this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See the manual for [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/delete):

> The `delete` operator deletes a property of an object

and

> If *`expression`* does not evaluate to a property, `delete` does nothing.

A variable is not a property.